# Find highest rate of change of any function

Tags: calculus, functions

Is there any way to find where the rate of change of function is maximum/highest?

Suppose we have a sine wave and i want to know where the rate of change of the function is maximum highest?

How can i find that?

Comment: Look for the extrema of the derivative, i.e., the zeros of the second derivative...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your function is $f(x)$

The rate of change of this function at an $x$ is $f'(x)$
$$Let\space f'(x)=g(x)$$
Now the rate of change of function $g(x)$ is $g'(x)=f''(x)$

You want to find the $x$ at which the rate of change of $f(x)$(which is $f'(x)=g(x))$ is maximum. This means you want to find $x$ at which $g(x)$ is maximum which would be at $g'(x)=0$, hence $$f''(x)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

This is standard maxima/minima, but here applied to the derivative (rate of change). Presumably you are interested in the magnitude (absolute value), not the value itself, thus maxima and minima.

Look for places where $f''(x) = 0$, check ends of the interval.